# Hawking radiatiom from our cosmic horizon

Tags: cosmology, universe, hawking-radiation

Does our Hubble radius/cosmic horizon emit Hawking radiation just like an empty de Sitter space would emit from its horizon?

Comment: note that the Hubble horizon is not the same thing as the cosmic horizon; you want the latter